# Vaadin EnumSelect getting length or size

Tags: java, vaadin

How can I get size or length of an Vaadin EnumSelect in Java. There's no size or lenght property there.

Something like this;

```
public enum ClassesType {
    AA, AB, BA, BB, CA, CB;
}

protected ClassesType myType;
```

and in another class I used `myType` as:

```
EnumSelect classes = new EnumSelect("Classes");
```

Then I wanted to say something like:

```
classes.values.length();
//or
classes.size();
```

and there was nothing.

Comment: Just a wild guess, the getValue() methos returns a object, which can be a array/list, depending of the multiselect status of tu UI component. So typecheck and the cast it to array/list and read the length/size property of that typecasted object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should have use my enum instead of my EnumSelect,

```
ClassesType.values.length();
```